# How to code and compile mql4 and mql5 language in VS Code?

Tags: mql4, mql5, forex, technical-indicator, expert-advisor

I moved to mql4 and mql5 programming language. But, MetaEditor is very noob to code with,
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVtJQ.png]
so I want to code mql4 language and compile with VS Code.

If you have any solution please share with us.....

Thanks

Comment: The simple answer is, you can't. The MQL4/5 compilers are provided for a reason.

Answer (score 5):

In the very early years of MQL4 ( MetaTrader Terminal, versions in about 2008-2010 ), there was a separate compiler programme, thus was configurable into other IDE ( me, using Geany-IDE ecosystem for doing this since ever )

After MQL4 language-revision, somewhere about 2009-2010 iirc, this option ceased to exist.

Inside MQL5 ecosystem, this option was available never.

The maximum achievable comfort thus remains in code-syntax highlights, code-completion configurations, if doable & done manually for the sake of your individual preferences ( me, using Geany-IDE ecosystem, being happy with MQL4-language configurations ( revised whenever MQL4 took further language specification revisions ) & copy/paste "technology" or `#include`-trick for moving between the two distinct ecosystems )

Answer (score 3):

There is a Extention(Plugin) in the VS Code called "MQL Tools", that can make you very easy to code MQL4 or  MQL5 language  , and compile with VS Code. You should try it.

Comment: The plugin you refer to does not allow you to compile MQL4/5 with VS code, it still uses MetaEditor for the compiling.

Answer (score 3):

If you open the Extensions tab and filter on MQL4, you'll find a MQL4 Syntax Highlight extension that also works for MQL5, and you'll find a MQL Tools extension that will add compilation options to VSCode.

Works perfect!